# Erase sum after threshold

Tags: c

I want to perform a column summation and once a certain threshold is met, I want to erase the summed so far value and not allow it to add any new values for the next 3 steps, but I am not sure how to do this. Can someone help me. Here is what I have so far.

```
for (i = 0; i < col; i++){
    sumC = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < row; j++)
    {
        sumC += matrix[j][i];

        if(sumC>1.5){
          sumC=0;     
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to add a counter `c` that resets after 3 steps:

```
int c = 0;
for (i = 0; i < col; i++) {
    sumC = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < row; j++)
    {
        if (c == 0) {
            sumC += matrix[j][i];
        } else {
            c = (c + 1) % 4;
        }

        if (sumC > 1.5) {
            sumC = 0;
            c++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works for me. Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could just advance the inner loop counter, e.g.

```
for (i = 0; i < col; i++) {
    sumC = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < row; j++)
    {
        sumC += matrix[j][i];

        if (sumC > 1.5) {
            sumC = 0;
            j += 3;            // <<<
        }
    }
}
```

NB: this assumes that you don't want to carry over the "next 3 steps" into the following column in the case where the threshold is reached near the end of a column.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know whether I understood corectelly:
put a variabke before the loop, let's say double Sumc2=Threshold.
Put a condituon IF, when reached the value to reset the Sumc and, in the sane sequence, encrease the step you want (i or j) with 3.